# How to fill the learning gaps before posting a question on MSE

Tags: discussion, help-suggestion

I am a self learning student of mathematics, that is I never had classroom experience beyond high school. I am seeking to self study this subject and often when I asked questions on MSE I find that I am lacking in the basic theories of calculus and algebra, and this gets my questions ignored (the solutions of which are not available on internet and I don't know where to begin with solving the questions I asked). So how do I become a productive member of the community? because I think I have a lot of learning gaps. Is there any resource from which I can practice and be confident enough to present proper mathematical proofs and also develop an expertise in solving the mathematical problems?

Comment: What is your background (experience in math classes (highschool) and self-study since then), and what are you trying to undertake in your current self-study?  No need to apologize for any lapses; you seem motivated and eager, so I commend you for that; but answering your question well requires we know better what you might have missed out on, or whether you've "bitten off more than you can chew".

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have completed a bachelor degree in mathematics through distance education and currently studying for a master. I therefore seek to be on par with others who expertise in mathematics as someone with a master's degree should.

Comment: Try to diagnose the earliest things you don't understand and ask about them. This is also the process for how to fill in learning gaps in math outside of math.se.

Comment: It seems like you're somewhat implicitly asking how to ask a good question - I think you would benefit from adding more context to your question, which includes specific work on a question as well as definitions - for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641231/how-are-the-following-congruence-relations-equivalent) question would greatly benefit if you had included what you *do* know about modular arithmetic (e.g. how was it defined? are there simpler congruences you do agree with - for instance, are ones without variables comfortable?)

Comment: ...In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3479765/how-to-integrate-int-c-fracz2z4-1-where-c-is-z-i-1) question, it seems like you realize that your trouble is in finding singularities - but your question asks about an integral! It would be better to narrow this question down - ask specifically about finding singularities (or, if you see that these are roots of $z^4+1$, about finding those) or, if possible, outline how to *use* this knowledge (so that you don't get answers that focus on something you know). Try to write narrow question that guide answerers to your trouble.

Comment: If your questions get ignored then try to improve the quality of your questions. Try to include your thoughts clearly. Overall there should be evidence of "good intent". Try to respond to any comments which are posted for your question and based on feedback improve the question.